# SQL Server reporting database updated with data from MySQL by scheduled job

Tags: mysql, sql

I am an ex multi value developer that over the last 6 months have been thrust in to the world of SQL and apologies in advance for the length of the question. So far I have got by with general instinct (maybe some ignorance!) and a lot of help from the good people on this site answering questions previously asked.

First some background …

I have an existing reporting database (SQL Server) and a new application (using MySQL) that I am looking to copy data from at either 30 min, hourly or daily intervals (will be based on reporting needs). I have a linked server created so that I can see the MySQL database from SQL Server and have relevant privileges on both databases to do read/writes/updates etc.

The data that I am looking to move to reporting on the 30 minute or hourly schedule typically are header/transactions by nature have both created and modified date/time stamp columns available for use.

Looking at the reporting DBs other feeds, Merge is the statement used most frequently across linked servers but to other SQL server databases. The merge statements also seem to do a full table to table comparison which in some cases takes a while (>5mins) to complete. Whilst the merge seems to be a safe options I do notice a performance hit on reporting whist the larger tables are being processed.

In looking at delta loads only, using dynamic date ranges (eg between -1 hour:00:00 and -1 hour:59:59) on created and modified time stamps, my concern would be the failure of any one job execution could leave the databases out of sync.

Rather than initially ask for specific sql statements what I am looking for is a general approach/statement design for the more regular (hourly) executed statements with the ideal being just to perform delta loads of the new or modified rows safely with a SQL Server to MySQL connection.

I hope the information given is sufficient and any help/suggestions/pointers to reading material gratefully accepted.

Thanks in advance

Darren

Comment: tmi dude tmi reproducible example

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I suppose the question is "how do I structure a query to take data (changes and inserts only) from MySQL to SQL Server every hour"

Answer (score -1):

I have done a bit of “playing” over the weekend.

The approach I have working pulls the data (inserts and updates) from MySQL via openquery into a CTE. I then merge the CTE into the SQL Server table.

The openquery seems slow (by comparison to other linked tables) but the merge is much faster due to limiting the amount of source data.